# ¿Como puestar en una DataFrame líneas de un fichero .js?

Tags: python, pandas, python-2.x

Hago una consulta a una base de datos SQL de la siguiente forma:

```
    cur.execute("""
    -- nombre de fois que les personnes ont interragi avec les pubs, 
    SELECT  COUNT (swipe.state),swipe.eclipse_id, swipe.subscriber_id FROM swipe
  WHERE swipe.state= 2 OR swipe.state = 3 or swipe.state=5 OR swipe.state =6 or swipe.state=8 or swipe.state=9
    GROUP BY swipe.subscriber_id,swipe.eclipse_id
      ORDER BY (swipe.subscriber_id) ASC
    """)
    n = cur.fetchall()
        listado_n = [{"count": elem[0], "eclipse_id": elem[1], "subscriber_id": elem[2]} for elem in n]
```

Con esto puedo construir un DataFrame de forma sencilla:

```
>>> df_n = pd.DataFrame(listado_n)
```

Con lo cual obtengo el siguiente DataFrame:

> ```
>      count  eclipse_id  subscriber_id
> 0        1     11243.0             54
> 1        1     11295.0             54
> 2        8     11294.0             54
> 3        7     11309.0            150
> 4        1     11265.0            150
> 5        1     11340.0            150
> ```

#### Mi proyecto : hacer lo mismo pero con ficheros :

Quiero hacer lo mismo, pero con el resultado de la consulta guardado en un archivo (`listado_n.js`). Cada linea del fichero se corresponde a un elemento de de la lista generada a partir de la consulta (`litado_n`). En el ejemplo anterior, el archivo tendría el siguiente contenido:

> {'count': 1L, 'subscriber_id': 54, 'eclipse_id': 11243}
>   {'count': 8L, 'subscriber_id': 54, 'eclipse_id': 11294}
>   {'count': 1L, 'subscriber_id': 54, 'eclipse_id': 11295}
>   {'count': 1L, 'subscriber_id': 150, 'eclipse_id': 11331}
>   {'count': 22L, 'subscriber_id': 150, 'eclipse_id': 10453}
>   {'count': 1L, 'subscriber_id': 150, 'eclipse_id': 11266}

Intento leerlo para obtener el DataFrame con el siguiente código:

```
listado_n = open("listado.js", "r").readlines()
listado = [{"count": elem[0], "eclipse_id": elem[1], "subscriber_id": elem[2]} for elem in listado_n]
df = pd.DataFrame(listado)
```

pero el DataFrame generado no es correcto:

> ```
> >>> print df
>
>     count eclipse_id subscriber_id
> 0       {          '             c
> 1       {          '             c
> 2       {          '             c
> 3       {          '             c
> 4       {          '             c
> 5       {          '             c
> ```

Comment: Marine es un poco extraño tu archivo, pareciera que es un JSON pero no lo es, son solo diccionarios ¿De donde obtienes o como creas este archivo?. El problema principal son los datos 2L, 8L, etc.. ¿Que son en realidad?¿Son cadenas o hacen referencia al tipo long de C?

Comment: @FJSevilla Hola  ! Obtengo el archivo con la consulta SQL de arriba. No sé porque los datos son con la *L* pero estan `int` o `long`, no lo sé.

Comment: Vale, eso es porque usas seguramente Python 2 para generar los datos. L indica un tipo long. En Python 3 este tipo desapareció (se unió con int) ¿Usas Python 3 o Python 2 para leer los datos? Si usas Python 2 es muy simple leer esas lineas como diccionarios.

Comment: @FJSevilla Pienso que utiliso python 2.7

Comment: Marine prueba la respuesta que he dejado, no obstante esto seguramente será lento si tienes muchos datos. Si esto es un problema para ti,  deberias considerar guardar esos datos con una estructura que pueda ser leida directamente por Pandas como un JSON o un csv. Saludos.

Comment: @FJSevilla muchas gracias ! Y muchas gracias por los consejos para el futuro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Los datos provienen por lo que comentas de una consulta SQL hecha desde Python 2. Si usas Python 2 para leerlos también lo más simple es usar la versión segura de `eval`, [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval), para pasar cada linea a un diccionario Python válido:

```
import pandas as pd
import ast

with open('listado.js') as f:
    data = (ast.literal_eval(line) for line in f.readlines())
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

**Salida:**

> ```
> >>> df
>    count  eclipse_id  subscriber_id
> 0      1       11243             54
> 1      8       11294             54
> 2      1       11295             54
> 3      1       11331            150
> 4     22       10453            150
> 5      1       11266            150
>
> >>> df.dtypes
> count            int64
> eclipse_id       int64
> subscriber_id    int64
> dtype: object
> ```